# .env gitignore? But use git for deployment?

Tags: amazon-web-services, github, environment-variables, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

What do I do if I have a .env file that I add to my .gitignore, but have my GitHub repo pipelined from GitHub to AWS elastic beanstalk for deployment?

Answer (score 1):

You should use Environment Variables in Elastic Beanstalk, by [configuring them as properties of the Elastic Beanstalk environment](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environments-cfg-softwaresettings.html), instead of depending on settings in a file.